# Java Factory to create Generic parameterised on the type passed

Tags: java, generics, factory

I've got a hangover, and I'm being particularly slow today.

I want to pass a subclass of `Intent` to some factory, and get back an `Handler<? extends Intent>`, where the parameterised type matches that of the argument passed to the factory.

```
public interface HandlerFactory
{
    <I extends Intent> Handler<I> build(I intent);
}
```

I'm struggling with the implementation of this. I don't want a big nasty if/else checking for all the different types of `Intent`, and then creating the appropriate `Handler<>` for each one, and casting it based on which conditional block we end up in. I don't want to use some variation of the Visitor pattern, as then my factory becomes coupled to *every* subclass of `Intent`/`Handler<? extends Intent>`. Something more 'pluggable' seems desirable.

How can I implement this without some filthy casting? The simplified case below doesn't compile because whilst `OrgHandler` implements `Handler<OrgIntent>`, the compiler doesn't *know* that the `Intent` passed (`I`) was an `OrgIntent` and not any other subclass.

```
public class SimpleHandlerFactory implements HandlerFactory
{    
    @Override
    public <I extends Intent> Handler<I> build(I intent)
    {
        // Filthy conditional that I want to avoid
        if(intent instanceof OrgIntent)
        {
            // Cast seems wrong
            return (Handler<I>) new SimpleOrgHandler(intent);
        }
        else if(intent instanceof SomeOtherIntent)
        {
            ...
    }
}
```

*Update*

The client code has a `List<Intent>` and doesn't really care about the subtypes; it needs to build a `List<Handler>` (I figure I'll need to have a raw types suppression there) and then call a method on each of those.

```
List<Intent> intents = orderedIntentBuilder.getOrderedIntents(declaration);
for(Intent intent : intents)
{
    Handler<Intent> handler = handlerFactory.build(intent);
    handler.resolve(someUnimportantArg);
}
```

Comment: One needs a parameter `Class<I> type`. Class and Handler can then be kept in a map.

Comment: "I've got a hangover", this amusing honesty gets you a thumb up :)

Answer (score 2):

I see the potential for a circular dependency here. You want to go from an `Intent` to a `Handler` while `Intent` is not supposed to know about `Handler`, and `Handler` already knows about `Intent`.

One could also wonder why a class needs a *dedicated* handler, shouldn't the handler functionality by part of the class itself then?

---

Any ways, one easy way is to add a `getHandler` method to `Intent`:

```
interface Handler<T extends Intent> {}

interface Intent {
    Handler<?> getHandler();
}

class OrgIntent {    
    @Override
    public Handler<OrgIntent> getHandler() {
        return new SimpleOrgHandler(this);
     }
}

...
List<Intent> intents = orderedIntentBuilder.getOrderedIntents(declaration);
for(Intent intent : intents)
{
    Handler<?> handler = intent.getHandler();
    handler.resolve(someUnimportantArg);
}
```

Which does create a circular dependency between the `Intent` and the `Handler`. Which you could be okay with, but there is also a way to solve that.

---

By extracting the data 'model' the handler operates on, into a third class:

```
interface IntentModel {...}
```

The `Handler` now operates on this model instead of the `Intent` itself.

```
class OrgIntent {    
    @Override
    public Handler<OrgIntentModel> getHandler() { // <-- Handler<OrgIntentModel>
        return new SimpleOrgHandler(this.model); // passing only model
    }
}
```

Which creates the dependencies:

```
Intent -> IntentModel
Intent -> Handler
Handler -> IntentModel
```

In this case you might want to merge the `Handler` functionality with the `IntentModel`. There would be no circular dependencies there, because the model only operates on itself.

Comment: Thanks. As it happens, the `Intent` classes are just data, and the rationale for the `Handler` classes is that I want to provide users of the library different ways of implementing behaviour that acts upon those data.

Comment: @EngineerBetter In that case, you should instantiate the handlers before ambiguating the intent type, so you can request the specific handler type, from a user provided factory (abstract factory pattern). It's hard to give an example without knowing more about the implementation of the ```IntentBuilder``` though.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the parameterized type to the factory class:

```
public interface HandlerFactory<I extends Intent> {
    Handler<I> build(I intent);
}
```

and your `SimpleHandlerFactory`:

```
public class SimpleHandlerFactory implements HandlerFactory<OrgIntent> {    
    @Override
    public Handler<OrgIntent> build(OrgIntent intent) {
        return new SimpleOrgHandler(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Does this just move the problem though? Now I need to look up the right factory, which again means going from having an `Intent` instance, and then having to find the right `HandlerFactory` which is parameterised by the `Intent` subclass?

Answer (score 1):

> As it happens, the Intent classes are just data, and the rationale for the Handler classes is that I want to provide users of the library different ways of implementing behaviour that acts upon those data.

So here's the other idea I had.

You could instantiate the functionality before ambiguating the intent type, here is a rough example:

- In this, `SomeInputType` would be the type from which you derive
  an intent's data.
- The type `Intent` is renamed to `IntentModel` (since it's just a
  data class).
- The type `Handler` is renamed to `Intent` (since this is where
  the real functionality is).

```
class OrgIntentModel implements IntentModel {
    public OrgIntentModel(SomeInputType input) {...}
}

// Abstract factory pattern
interface IntentFactory {
    // Constructs an Intent with custom behaviour.
    // Using the data in the specific model.
    Intent getOrgIntent(OrgIntentModel model);

    // Getters for each model type
}

// This class is implemented by the user.
// You could provide a 'DefaultFactory' as a template to extend.
class UserProvidedFactory implements IntentFactory {...}

class IntentBuilder { // i.e. IntentDeserializer

    private Map<String, Function<? super SomeInputType, ? extends Intent>> map;

    public IntentBuilder(IntentFactory factory) {
        map.put("OrgIntent", makeFunc(OrgIntentModel::new, factory::getOrgIntent));
        // other mappings...
    }

    // Helper method, to help with casting the method references.
    // 'U' represents the specific IntentModel.
    // SomeInputType -> IntentModel -> Intent
    private static <T, U, R> Function<T, R> makeFunc(
        Function<T, ? extends U> f1,
        Function<? super U, R> f2) {
        return f1.andThen(f2);
    }

    public Intent getIntent(SomeInputType input) {
        String intentType = input.getIntentType();
        return map.get(intentType).apply(input);
    }
}
```